# Angular 2 Modal popup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I created modal popup using Angular 2, I want the modal popup to be movable. Can anyone help?

Below link is the image of current stage.
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrFuG.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have been trying and explain what problems you're facing.

Comment: It seems that you are new to StackOverflow, I suggest you to have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Noone is going to help you. Who will want to download rar archive, run code, etc. Create a demo plunkr, post link here. Then *maybe*..

Comment: Use plunker for your sample code to post on StackOverflow. It seems you need to write some z-index manupulation logic based on your event. Please edit your question with more information.